# Use output results as data for more calculations - R

Tags: r

I am totally novel in using R and I am stuck in my analyses. I have used a function to do some calculations with my data. Once I got the results (pasted below) I need to use them again to calculate the mean of the variable "PX" but I do not know how to proceed. I have tried several options but without success. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for this (probably) vague question.

```
ndiv <- fitplcs(data,
                "Sample",
                varnames=c(PLC="PLC", WP="PSI"),
                weights=NULL,
                random =NULL,
                model= "sigmoidal",
                x = 50,
                coverage = 0.95,
                bootci = TRUE,
                nboot = 50,
                quiet = TRUE,
                startvalues = NULL)
ndiv

# Group:  PH_1 
    Estimate Boot - 2.5% Boot - 97.5%
SX 31.649016   20.219422    41.891662
PX  4.049126    3.813595     4.623607

# Group:  PH_1-Pink 
    Estimate Boot - 2.5% Boot - 97.5%
SX 27.062688   18.110285    32.795379
PX  5.430344    5.123864     6.292341

# Group:  PH_1b 
    Estimate Boot - 2.5% Boot - 97.5%
SX 35.411346   28.955444    43.805794
PX  4.098899    3.940512     4.394827

# Group:  PH_2 
    Estimate Boot - 2.5% Boot - 97.5%
SX 40.033074   16.774300    70.725351
PX  4.052401    3.553234     5.717543
```

Comment: Please provide some data we can work with.

Comment: Welcome. Please provide the code that generated this output. The technique for capturing it will depend on how it was generated. Remember that we need to run it to give us the best chance of answering helpfully, so include all the code, including library() and any raw data.

Comment: Thanks GGamba, but how can I do that? Sorry...

Comment: depending on the function you are using it returns values into a list you can access to or you can input into your own list. (sometimes vectors or matrices). Something like result[3] or result$estimates etc.. Short of knowing what function you are using with a data example it is hard to help

Comment: Ok, the code is: library(fitplc). And this is how I am doing my calculations: indiv <- fitplcs(data, "Sample", varnames=c(PLC="PLC", WP="PSI"), weights=NULL, random =NULL, model= "sigmoidal", x = 50,
                 coverage = 0.95, bootci = TRUE, nboot = 50, quiet = TRUE, startvalues = NULL).  How can I provide you with some data?

Comment: better to edit your question and add some sample data using the output from  dput(mydata) from R.

Comment: call `str(ndiv)` on your results - it's proably a form of list object, then navigate to the results you want via indexing or `$`, e.g. `ndiv$group1$Estimate` or `ndiv[[1]][[1]]` or whatever the structure is

Comment: is your output a list??

Comment: I think the output is a list. This is what I get using dput(mydata):         0.989672175181064, 0.990529966447849, 0.991317137782823, 
        0.9920394034494, 0.992702031266215, 0.993309874924791
        ), upr = c(0.0542178081755347, 0.0583302578590484, 0.0627339485579037, 
        0.0674462873212079, 0.0724852241061352, 0.0778691868387237, 
        0.083617000601776, 0.08974778935741, 0.096280858668634, 
        0.103235558000471, 0.110631121368264, 0.118486485370451,

Comment: Looking at the documentation for that package it seems you can use coef() but with out knowing the structure of your output and what values you are trying to extract it is almost impossible to provide a certain answer

Comment: Thanks friffinevo! Using coef() I got the following. My aim now is average all sx and px "Estimate" values, and it is here where I am stuck now:     Group Parameter  Estimate Boot - 2.5% Boot - 97.5%
1        PH_1        SX 31.649016   20.219422    41.891662
2        PH_1        PX  4.049126    3.813595     4.623607
3   PH_1-Pink        SX 27.062688   18.110285    32.795379
4   PH_1-Pink        PX  5.430344    5.123864     6.292341
5       PH_1b        SX 35.411346   28.955444    43.805794
6       PH_1b        PX  4.098899    3.940512     4.394827